# edge browser auto close when going to my website

Tags: javascript

So i have a website and i dont want users to use microft edge

is there any way when user open site on edge it sends an alert - edge is not compatible and closes the broswer automatically or when clicked ok from the alert?

i found this but i dont know how to work it together\

```
<script>
if (/Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    {alert('Microsoft Edge is not compatible. please use a different browser');}

}
</script>



<script language="javascript">

function quitBox(cmd) 
{      
    if (cmd=='quit')    
    {
       open(location, '_self').close();    
    }     
    return false;   
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (/Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  alert("not compatible message here")
  window.close()
}
```

Comment: thank you.. that works.. anyways to make it auto? so they dont have to answer yes or no?

Comment: sorry for not answering earlier, @codermr. You can delete the line that says `alert` if you want it to be automatic.